# Xamarin Page Renderer WinRT Desktop UserControl not rendered

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've tried to adding a Xaml UserControl and/or UserPage in WIndows Desktop project added in Xamarin. None of Windows UI items (page or usercontrol and buttons) are displayed by page renderer. Can you please help where could I be making mistake.

**CameraPageRenderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Shared.CameraPage), typeof(CameraPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Windows
{
public class CameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
             //1st test
            this.Children.Add(new PhotoCaptureControl());
             //[OR] 2nd Test
            this.Children.Add(new PhotoCapturePage());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger class
        }
    }

}
```

**CameraPage**
Invoked from Portable library page

```
public class CameraPage : ContentPage
   {

    public CameraPage(TaskCompletionSource<MediaFile> SelectionTask)
    { 
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
        };
    }
}
```

**PhotoCaptureControl.xaml**
.cs file has Initialize method.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Windows.PhotoCaptureControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Windows"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="400"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Text="Capture Photo text" />

    <Button x:Name="BtnCapturePhoto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Capture Photo" />
</StackPanel>    
</UserControl>
```

**PhotoCapturePage.xaml** .cs contains InitializeComponents() method

```
<Page x:Class="eWorker.Windows.PhotoCapturePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:eWorker.Windows"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="BtnCapturePhoto"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Capture Photo" />

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to my problem. It will work in case of `PhotoCapturePage` but may not in case of UserControl `PhotoCaptureControl`.

I replaced following line of code

```
this.Children.Add(new PhotoCapturePage());
```

with -

```
 this.SetNativeControl(new PhotoCapturePage());
```

This solution will not work if it is required to add one or more native UserControl.